# how to use only 1 shipping option for the paypal cart

Tags: html, paypal

im using a multi-item cart with paypal

the problem is i need to send a general shipping and not to send shipping for each product actually im using this code:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="3.99">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="6.99">
```

but i need to use only 1 shipping for the whole cart

so if i use:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="6.99">
```

it wont show on paypal

Answer (score 0):

`shipping_x` should work.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXX@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="US">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="beach ball">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="towel">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="2.00">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

though shipping_x is passed, the checkout page will display as `shipping=7`[image]

Or you can setup [profile based shipping](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-shipping)